# my newly created python package has replaced _ in the name with -

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have created my first python package using setuptools.  Running `python -m build` from the top level of my package directory seems to make the package just fine, and the package files are created in dist as expected.  However when I install the package, the name of the installed package has the _ replaced by -, making it almost impossible to import into a python file.

Here is my directory layout:

```
(venv) cunninwe@MBLS015 dpu2 % tree /Users/cunninwe/Documents/dpu2
/Users/cunninwe/Documents/dpu2
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── myorg_devops_utils-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── myorg_devops_utils-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── devops_python_utils_package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── file0.py
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   ├── file2.py
│   │   ├── file3.py
│   │   ├── fileA.py
│   │   ├── file4.py
│   │   ├── file5.py
│   │   ├── file6.py
│   │   ├── file7.py
│   │   ├── fileB.py
│   │   ├── rcfile.rc
│   │   ├── file8.py
│   │   ├── file9.py
│   │   └── file10.py
│   └── myorg_devops_utils.egg-info
│       ├── PKG-INFO
│       ├── SOURCES.txt
│       ├── dependency_links.txt
│       └── top_level.txt
├── tests
│   ├── test_file1.py
│   ├── test_file2.py
│   ├── test_file3.py
│   ├── test_file4.py
│   ├── test_file5.py
│   ├── test_file6.py
│   ├── test_file7.py
│   └── test_file8.py
└── venv
```

My pyproject.toml file like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "myorg_devops_utils"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name="me", email="me@myorg.com" },
]
description = "Python utilities used by DevOps team"
readme = "README.md"
license = { file="LICENSE" }
requires-python = ">=3.9"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
```

I am running `python -m build` from the root of this structure.  I then change into the dist subdirectory and run the pip install of the whl file.

```
(venv) cunninwe@MBLS015 dist % python -m pip install myorg_devops_utils-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./myorg_devops_utils-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: myorg-devops-utils
Successfully installed myorg-devops-utils-0.0.1
```

Environment:  Mac

So:

1. Why did this happen?
2. How do I make it go away so I can actually use files from my package?

I have tried using `importlib.import_module('myorg-devops-utils')` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The names of the import packages and import modules should not have changed. If they did, then something went really wrong. It is okay for the name of the distribution package to have underscores `_` be replaced with dashes `-`, they are equivalent in the Python packaging ecosystem (one is the canonical form). -- Your real issue is that your top-level import package is `devops_python_utils_package`(and not `myorg_devops_utils`, as you seem to be expecting, which is the name of your distribution package). So you need to `import devops_python_utils_package`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real issue is that your top-level import package is `devops_python_utils_package` (and not `myorg_devops_utils`, as you seem to be expecting, which is the name of your distribution package). So you need to `import devops_python_utils_package`.

---

The names of the import packages and import modules should not have changed. If they did, then something went really wrong. On the other hand, it is okay for the name of the distribution package to have its underscores `_` be replaced with dashes `-`, they are equivalent in the Python packaging ecosystem (one is the canonical form).